# loop over parameterized rest api call

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a history load of data from a ReST api call using powershell. If I were to call the ReST endpoint with no parameters I either run into timeout or out of memory exceptions.

```
$Header = @{
    "authorization" = "Bearer $token"
}
#make REST API call
$Parameters = @{
    Method      = "GET"
    Headers     = $Header
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Body        = $BodyJson
}
$startYear = 2014
$endYear = 2022

$Data = {for($year=$startYear; $i -le $endYear; $year=$year+1) {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data/year/Year/" + [string]$year @params -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Stop}} | ConvertTo-Json
```

tried the below as well.

```
    $Data = foreach($year in $startYear..$endYear) {
        $url = "https://api.mysite.com/v1/data/year/Year/" + [string]$year 
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url @params -DisableKeepAlive -ErrorAction Stop}

$Data | ConvertTo-Json
```

I don't see all of the data starting from the year 2010 until the year 2022. Also, I would like to append `$Data` with all the data starting from the year 2010 until the current year.

Comment: With ```{ foreach ... } | ConvertTo-Json``` you're trying to convert the **definition** of a scriptblock, not the results of **executing** the scriptblock. Similarly with ```{Invoke-RestMethod ... }``` you're just definining a scriptbloxk, not executing it. Remove the enclosing ```{ ... }``` from both and you'll get nearer to a working solution...

Comment: Hi @mclayton, Thanks for your inputs. I did modify the code accordingly. But I see only a year worth of data. I'm trying to append all the data into one big json document.